# Ajax and PHP session issue, simple test wont work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Having a weird problem, session not being stored when doing ajax requests from js (localhost).

I have created an simple demo that I expected to work, but session is never being stored. However if I access the php script directly from my webbrowser it works as expected and stores session.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'http://example.com/test.php',
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* Session start */
session_start();

/* Set headers */
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
header('Content-Type: application/json');

if (!isset($_SESSION['test'])) {
    $_SESSION['test'] = 'abc';
    $result = 'session_set';

} else {
    $result = $_SESSION['test'];
}

echo json_encode(array('result' => $result));

?>
```

Comment: Check for errors in the console and in your php script.

Comment: No php errors and no js console errors. Checked php log files and tried adding `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of the php script. Allways returns "session_set".

Comment: You are trying to call `ajax` when the page loaded. So use `$(function(){...//your ajax method....// })`

Comment: you should use your ajax inside this function `$(function(){ // write your ajax here  });`

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't work. I also updated my original post and you can see I have added `$(function() { });` around the ajax request.

Comment: if you have set `dataType: 'json',` in ajax then you don't need to set set headers in php script as `dataType:'json'` will do it for you  `/* Set headers */
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: @BadshahSahib doesn't help me with my problem. If I set `header('Content-Type: application/json');` the response is in json format not plain/text or text/html. And setting dataType: 'json' I am telling my ajax request to expect json data. This is not were the problem is.

Comment: So, do you have found any error message in console. check the errors in console and paste here.

Comment: No errors in js console or in php log files. The php script itself is not dumping any warnings or errors as well.

Comment: `ob_start() ` before session start and `ob_clean` before `echo json_encode`

Comment: @BadshahSahib doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is cross-domain limitation, isnt that a problem?

Comment: `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` should solve that?

Comment: Depends. I think you cant create session on www.site-one.com calling it from www.site-two.com. header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); enable ajax to call site-one.com.

Comment: I have done it before. Created a hybrid mobile application that used php backend and I logged in and it stored session properly and everything worked. This is like 3-4 years ago.

Comment: I think you're right. Since the two files are not running on the same host I cannot store session on the one side. I've managed to it before but then I used trigger.io request module.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check if your browser is receiving the `Set-Cookie` header from the server on the AJAX request.

Secondly, check if the browser is storing the cookie and sending it on subsequent requests and you're not getting any new `Set-Cookie` response from server.

If any of the statements above are false, there might be a problem with with server configuration, for example the session id is set to be stored in URL - which will obviously not work.

Sorry to say it, but it works swimmingly for me on localhost.

---

If you are trying to do this cross-domain, well, that's impossible, because cross-domain cookies don't exist.

Comment: Yes it will work if both files are on localhost. But I want to do a cross domain request. Where the php file is on example.com and the js is running on localhost.